# Is it possible to make an advanced rich text editor for web that would allow copy-pasting of pictures?

Tags: richtextbox

## The long story:

The larger problem is that I'm trying to convince people from switching away from Outlook to a more sane bugtracker, preferably web-based that we could also use as a public bugtracker. But the current argument against it is that the Outlook editor (which is really Word with all the bells and whistles) allows easy inserting of pictures, advanced formatting, etc. So I wonder if I'm at a dead end, or there is hope yet.

## The problem in a nutshell:

I want to know - **is it possible** to create a website component that would be a REALLY powerful rich text editor. A must-have feature is to insert pictures into the editor straight from the clipboard. Better yet - **does something like that exist**?

There is no limit on the allowed technology. It can be flash based, java based, work only in IE, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible: Yes, but not with JavaScript alone. You will need a plugin or client software to accomplish this.

As far as the technology allowed, this really depends on how you want to implement it. You could use the JRE and write everything in Java. If you're more focused on IE you might consider VB or C#.

Comment: I didn't expect it to be possible with JS alone. Flash would be preferred, of course (because it's ubiquitous today), but other technologies would work as well. Perhaps you know of a complete solution?